# Cropping an triangle from captured frame - OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, crop

I have a video file from which I'm capturing a frames. I want to crop a triangle from captured frame and display it, but my program shows just a source frame.

Here is my code:

```
cv::Mat Detector::cropRegionOfInterest(cv::Mat& frame)
{
    cv::Point corners[1][3];
    corners[0][0] = cv::Point(0, frameHeight);
    corners[0][1] = cv::Point(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    corners[0][2] = cv::Point(frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2);

    const cv::Point* cornerList[1] = { corners[0] };

    int numPoints = 3;
    int numPolygons = 1;

    cv::Mat mask(frame.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    cv::fillPoly(mask, cornerList, &numPoints, numPolygons, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 8);

    cv::Mat result(frame.size(), CV_8UC3);
    cv::bitwise_and(frame, mask, result);

    return result;
}
```

Instead of displaying source frame I want it to display cropped triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `CV_8UC3` as the type of `result`, I'm assuming (see the Edit at the end of the answer if that's not the case) that the input image `frame` also has `3` channels. In that case, I'm a bit surprised that you can even see the non-cropped image, as running your code simply throws an exception on my machine at the call to `bitwise_and`:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14), it seems to me that you can't mix different input and mask types. A quick and dirty solution is to split the input image into a vector of three channels, call `bitwise_and` for each of them, and then merge them back. The code below works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;


cv::Mat cropRegionOfInterest(cv::Mat& frame)
{

    const int frameWidth=frame.cols-1;
    const int frameHeight=frame.rows-1;
    cv::Point corners[1][3];
    corners[0][0] = cv::Point(0, frameHeight);
    corners[0][1] = cv::Point(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    corners[0][2] = cv::Point(frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2);

    const cv::Point* cornerList[1] = { corners[0] }; 

    int numPoints = 3; 
    int numPolygons = 1; 

    cv::Mat mask(frame.rows,frame.cols, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    cv::fillPoly(mask, cornerList, &numPoints, numPolygons, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 8);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> src_channels;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> result_channels;
    cv::split(frame,src_channels);

    for(int idx=0;idx<3;++idx)
    {  
      result_channels.emplace_back(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_8UC1);
      cv::bitwise_and(src_channels[idx], mask,result_channels[idx]);

    }  
    cv::Mat result;
    cv::merge(result_channels,result);
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {  
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }  

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 ); 

    if ( !image.data )
    {  
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }  

    cv::Mat cropped=cropRegionOfInterest(image);

    namedWindow("cropped Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 
    imshow("cropped Image", cropped);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0; 
}
```

---

**Edit:** From your comments it seems that `frame` is actually grayscale. In that case, nevermind all the code above, and just change `cv::Mat result(frame.size(), CV_8UC3);` to

```
cv::Mat result(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_8UC1);
```

in your original code.

Comment: @msk Ah that's weird. At which line?

Comment: @msk Also, how did you run it? Which opencv version are you using? Try to add as much info as possible. Saying it segfaults isn't very helpful in itself. That also holds for your question, as you see I had to guess the type of your input frame ;)

Comment: I think it's throws segfault after first iteration of loop is done.

Comment: I'm using 3.4.1 version and frames are captured from mp4 video file

Comment: @msk Hmmm that's very strange, as it is running just fine on my machine. Can you run my code in the command line with an arbitrary RGB image? If it works then I think the problem might come from `frame.type()`...

Comment: @msk Also another thing, can you add an example of your frames to the question?

Comment: I run your code with an RGB image and it works fine. Can problem be in that I'm converting a frame to a grayscale and then trying to crop it?

Comment: @msk Ah yes that is the reason. Then you original code just needs a tiny modification: when you declare `result`, use `CV_8UC1` instead of `CV_8U3`. That works fine with grayscale for me.

Comment: @msk Just in case I wasn't clear, I meant that your original code was fine except for this `CV_8UC1` thing, and you don't need any of the code I wrote.